# Issues with Screen Flashing and Saturation on Boot

Tags: boot, dual-boot, system-installation, 22.04

I'm quite new to Ubuntu and in general, aren't very tech literate. My system is a tower I built myself. The specs of the tower are; core i9 10850k, rtx 3060 12gb, 32gb RAM, Z590 AORUS ELITE AX motherboard, 3tb SSD storage; it runs windows 11. (I'm tying to install Ubuntu version 22.04.2.)

I got a separate 1TB SSD drive for linux on my tower. I need windows 11 on my main machine since all my work is done in the Adobe suite and it has a hard enough time running on Windows. It went onto the drive just fine; but it's totally borked. I get a number of lines saying "ACPI BIOS error (bug):Could not resolve symbol." On boot.

After that, all the images on the screen flash. As in, the search bar and stuff will appear for a second, then go away for 10 seconds. My mouse cursor is only on the screen when all the UI isn't showing. For the brief moment the UI does show, it looks like normal Ubuntu. Also, I have two monitors, but only one of them gets used. The other stays black.

Even weirder, it sorta works if I boot off my thumb drive that I use for instillation. It does run if I go to 'try Ubuntu'. However, each screen is very over-saturated with a different color. One screen, everything is bright red, the other everything is bright yellow.

I have a feeling this all has something to do with the graphics drivers. I did a little searching and found a guide on how to update them through Ubuntu but it didn't fix anything. Since then I've removed it from my machine.

Any ideas what's going on? I have pictures of all this in a google drive folder that I've linked. I'd put them in this post but I'm not allowed to embed images yet.

Any help is greatly appreciated. I love the layout and speed of Ubuntu and wanna get it working on my tower.

Here's the google drive folder with images of these issues.
https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1G9oAWEhNEBZ-OUZ5E0RuMJXdMoDpAeyl?usp=sharing

Comment: @Nmath
I made some edits based on your suggestions. How does this look?

Comment: When you install Ubuntu, make sure it's connected to the internet and make sure you choose the two options: download updates while installing and accept third party proprietary drivers. These options should ensure that the correct proprietary Nvidia driver is being used. But it is a little concerning if you're having the same problem when using the live session. Perhaps because you have newer hardware, you may need a newer release of Ubuntu. It may work to install Ubuntu 23.04 since it has a newer kernel and stack.